# How to store/create a MongoDB config file for production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm currently working on a bachelors project using the MERN stack.

As of now I have a dbconfig file which stores the mongodb passcode.

My question is how should I go about this when delivering the project to the business? Should it be stated that they must create this file themselves and enter their passcode there?
Is it my responsibility to help them set this up, even though this could compromise security if lets say I had malicious intentions?

Or should I implement a system with for example a prompt letting them input this on runtime?

I'm not looking for exact answers, but any pointers from someone with experience delivering products or alike would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Usually you would explain your customer where he has to put the credentials. Or when your setup is more advanced then the setup program will prompt for a password and writes it into the config file.

Comment: Just note, your customer has to trust you anyway. I guess you use Windows and/or office, i.e. in the end you have to trust Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I figured it was going to be more complicated, but I guess I'm creating my own problems over complicating things. The project is only a webapplication with some authorization so I'll skip the promt and explain to them how to set-up the database on delivery.